# How to create a custom annotation in Java like Spring @Value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-annotations, annotation-processing

I have a use case where I have to assign a default value to a field in my pojo when a certain criteria is met. I have already created a custom annotation which will check for the criteria, but I'm not knowing how to set the default value to the field.

Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: Why not to just use constructor?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I cannot use a constructor because, this pojo will have values sent by external system which has to be validated and can be modified only when a certain criteria is met.

Comment: So, what's the problem to do your validations or whatever in the constructor? or define a setter injection and do all necessary stuff there.. I don't get your problem.

Comment: I have like around 100+ fields to be validated and throw exception accordingly. Is it a good practice to write those many if else blocks in constructor?

Comment: 100+ fields to be validated is a very bad software design, per se, and note, that I'm not talking about *whether it's good to validate 100+ fields in the constructor*.. definitely it is not.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I thought I can use annotation. I'm using javax.validation to check length, nonnull and custom annotation for business criteria. Now my only challenge is to assign default value. So I thought I can write an annotation like @value in spring